# method returns null along with a part of the output

Tags: java, null

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test
{
    public static String plainTxt;
    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        
        System.out.print("Enter the word you want to encrypt: ");
        
        String word1 = scan.next();
        String word2 = scan.next();
        String word3 = scan.next();
        
        plainTxt = word1 + word2 + word3; 
        
        Cipher cipher = new Cipher();
        
        cipher.plainTxt1 = plainTxt;
        
        String cryptTxt = cipher.shifter();
        
        System.out.println(cryptTxt.substring(0, word1.length()) + " " + cryptTxt.substring(word1.length(), word1.length() + word2.length()) + " " +
                   cryptTxt.substring(word1.length() + word2.length(), plainTxt.length()));
    
    }
}




class Cipher
{
    public String output;
    public int limit = 0;
    public char chr;
    public String plainTxt1;
    
    public Cipher()
    {
        limit = 0;
    }
    
    
    public String shifter()
    {
        if(plainTxt1.charAt(limit) == 'z' || plainTxt1.charAt(limit) == 'y')
            chr = (char)((int)plainTxt1.charAt(limit) - 23);
        else if(plainTxt1.charAt(limit) == 'x')
            chr = (char)((int)plainTxt1.charAt(limit) - 23);
        else 
            chr = (char)((int)plainTxt1.charAt(limit) + 3); 

        limit += 1;
        
        output += chr;
        
        if(limit == 11)
            return output;
        else
            shifter();
        
        return output;
    }
}
```

hello
Im a beginner and this was an alternative solution to a homework question I have. Ill not be using this solution as an answer but Im still curious if there is a way to use a recursive function as a loop to caeser cypher a given 14 character input. for context a caeser cypher is an algorithm where shift the input characters by a given amount to the right or left. For this one we shift 3 character to the right. My main question is why does the code above return null along with the first 8 characters of the output excluding whitespaces?

Comment: Show all your imports please, we don't know where does Cipher come from, is it `import javax.crypto.Cipher;`?

Comment: I didnt use any imports besides the scanner. The cipher class is right under the main method.

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't see that it had code below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method is returning null because the output instance variable in the Cipher class is not instantiated so it has the null value (String variables in Java have a null value when they are not instantiated). All you should do is this change:

public String output = "";

Comment: Ooh I see. Thanks for your answer it did solve the issue but does this also mean even though I called the function again before the return statement the one I called first still returns the output?

Answer (score 1):

Change the Cipher class to this

```
class Cipher {
  public String encryptedText;
  public int limit;
  public char chr;
  public String plainTxt;

  public Cipher() {
    encryptedText = "";
    limit = 0;
  }

  public String shifter() {
    shiftCharacter();
    limit += 1;
    encryptedText += chr;
    if (limit == plainTxt.length())
        return encryptedText;
    else
        shifter();
    return encryptedText;
  }

  public void shiftCharacter() {
    if (plainTxt.charAt(limit) == 'z' || plainTxt.charAt(limit) == 'y')
        chr = (char) ((int) plainTxt.charAt(limit) - 23);
    else if (plainTxt.charAt(limit) == 'x')
        chr = (char) ((int) plainTxt.charAt(limit) - 23);
    else
        chr = (char) ((int) plainTxt.charAt(limit) + 3);
  } 
}
```

The changed the if(limit == 11) condition to if (limit == plainTxt.length()). Also I initialized the encrypted text in the default constructor.